# Are all iPhone/iPod accessories are compatible with iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, compatibility

I bought an iPad 2 recently, and tried to buy some accessories such as a cigarette charger or something. What I found was that I can't find accessories for iPad, and the accessory box says it is for iPod/iPhone/iPod Touch, but there was no mention about iPad.

Is that because all the iPhone/iPod accessories are compatible with iPad? I mean, if it's for iPhone/iPod, is it always also for iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the lack of accessories may be due to the power requirements of the iPad.

The iPad comes with a 10 watt charger while most iPhone chargers are only 1 watt. According to this article lower wattage chargers will work, they will just be slower.

http://m.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/04/ipad-battery-charging/